# Welcome screen without Customize and Learn sections

Tags: visual-studio-code

On Visual Studio Code version 1.59.1 the Help, Customize and Learn features are not present, as shown on Getting started with Visual Studio Code video tutorial from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/basics

What should I do to include them in welcome screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That video is just over a year old now according to the date on the page, and the Welcome Screen no longer looks like that with the current version of Visual Studio Code.

However, you can still access many, if not all of these from the "Open a Walkthrough" option present on the welcome page.  This should open a drop down where you can choose from different options to learn more about Visual Studio Code.

[image]

You will have to look through these options, but as an example, the settings option can be found under the "Learn the Fundamentals" section:

[image]

Comment: Hello again, I have clicked on Open a Walkthrough" option, but when I click on "Get Started with VS Code" or "Learn the Fundamentals" or Boost your Productivity" options nothing happens. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: @Bogdan the screen should transition into whichever guide you clicked on.  If it doesn't... I really don't know what else you can try.  Perhaps make sure your Visual Studio Code is updated to the current version.

Comment: By chance, I tried to install C# extension, and I have run into an error regarding the missing .NET SDK. After searching in VS Code documentation I have encountered the .NET Coding Pack, which included VS Code, NET SDK and .NET extension pack for VS Code. Turned that whitout NET SDK and .NET extension pack, VS Code lacked the interaction ability. Everything is working fine now.

Comment: @Bogdan interesting, glad to hear you worked it out.  If you found the answer useful, be sure to mark it accepted/vote.